# Push Notification iOS não chega.Xamarin

Tags: xamarin-forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

Estou com a seguinte situação, criei dentro do developer.apple um Apple Push Notifications service (APNs), e adicionei la no firebase (Chave de autenticação de APNs). Tudo certinho (pelo menos acho que seja só isso).

E configurei meu back-end para enviar meus push através do Firebase, nos app android está perfeito, no iOS não chega de forma nenhuma.

Alguém tem alguma dica que possa me ajudar?
Usei no projeto Xamarin - https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin

E no back-end - https://github.com/angelobelchior/FCM.Net

Comment: Como você gerou o certificado de push? de produção ou development?

Comment: Usei um certificado em produção para publicar na apple store. Eu gerei uma key em https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/authkey/ e maquei essa opção Apple Push Notifications service (APNs) e adicionei esse arquivo dentro do firebase